# In a Maven multi-module project, how to specify dependency needed in more than one module?

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I know that the intent of a multi-module Maven project is that each module can be compiled and built separately as well as collectively from the parent.

Suppose two of my [three modules](https://vaadin.com/maven#archetypes) need to use the [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) library. Do I specify that dependency in the POM of each of the two sub-modules? If so, what “scope”? Or do I specify the dependency in the parent module? I need Guava bundled in my final product, but I certainly don't need two copies.

Comment: In this case the common approach would be to use the `dependencyManagement` in parent module and add your Guava dependency there. In the child modules you add the dependency to guava without the version and scope (this will be handled by the parent). This will prevent different modules with a library with different versions. AFAIK there is no way to say to maven to not generate "two copies" of  a dependency if your modules are generating two separate JARs. If it is a web module it will not create copies....

Comment: I don't think you need to worry about it since even though you have two copies in the classpath of the same jar, one of then will be ignored upon loading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually declare all dependencies in `dependencyManagement` of the parent project and then use them in `depenencies` of modules, but without `version`. Versions are only declared in the parent project.

As for `scope`, I normally don't declare scope in parent unless it is something very obvious like JUnit.

> Do I specify that dependency in the POM of each of the two sub-modules?

If you use this dependency directly, then yes. Even if it would be included transitively.

> If so, what “scope”?

This depends on what the dependency is and how you use it. Guava will normally be `compile`.

> Or do I specify the dependency in the parent module?

You can declare it in `dependencyManagement` in parent so that you don't have to specify the version anywhere else.

But you normally will not declare the dependency in the parent module as it will be inherited by all the child modules. This is usually too much of an assumption.

> I need Guava bundled in my final product, but I certainly don't need two copies.

Won't happen.

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose two of my three modules need to use the Google Guava library. Do I specify that dependency in the POM of each of the two sub-modules?

It depends what is the relation between those modules and what you do with them; let's call them `moduleA`, `moduleB` (the modules that share a dependency), and `moduleC` (the third module).

How do you deploy `moduleA` and `moduleB`? Does it make sense that each have their own copy of the same library ?

- For example if they're both WARs that run independently, you'll want to give each, its own copy of the library.
- If they're both jars that end up in the same war (possibly represented by `moduleC`), then you'll want to give each of them the dependency with `scope=provided`, and add a third dependency in the `moduleC` with the default scope.

> Or do I specify the dependency in the parent module?

The problem with specifying the dependency in the parent module is that the dependency will also be picked up by `moduleC` which might not be what you want.

One possibility to solve this (for example if `moduleA` and `moduleB` share *a lot* of dependencies, or common properties or settings) is to add a common parent:

- An extra parent pom / reactor for `moduleA` and `moduleB`, but NOT for `moduleC`.
- This extra parent pom would be on the same level in the tree with `moduleC` (and so it would have, in turn, the same parent as `moduleC`).
- It would contain whatever `moduleA` and `moduleB` have in common.

Comment: I am not seeing the third sub-module picking up the dependency (good). In parent, I have the specify the dependency with a `groupid`, `artifactid`, and `version`. In each of the two submodules, I omit the `version`. The IntelliJ `Maven` panel shows each of the two submodules with a copy of the Guava library but not the third submodule (good). In the `WEB-INF/lib` folder of my built Vaadin 8 (Java Servlet) project, I find a list of libraries with just one Guava. So I suppose this is good enough for me. But I've not yet implemented unit-testing in each module.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand 100%. If the 3 modules share one dependency when you intended only 2 of them to have it, you'll still end up with just one jar in `WEB-INF/lib`, because the dependency will have the same name in all 3 cases, so only one of them will "win" (the other 2 copies will get overwritten due to files having the exact same name).

Comment: I am referring to the part about specifying the dependency in the parent module. The submodules only gain a copy in the intermediate stage (`IntelliJ` > `Maven Projects` > `my-sub-module` >  `Dependencies`) if the POM for that submodule has a `<dependency><groupid><artifactid>` specified but omitting the version number (where parent POM specifies the `<version>`).

Comment: If you specify the dependency in the parent, the children will get a copy(with the same scope as in parent) in all cases. The version inheritance is just for omitting specifying it twice. It does not have effect on inclusion strategy. Be sure not to confuse `dependencies` with `dependencyManagement`.